# How can I reinitialize a UIViewRepresentable when a value changes?

Tags: swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

So let's say we have the following code:

```
struct MyView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var myValue: Int
        
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MyOtherView {
        let someValue = SomeController()
        
        return MyOtherView(someValue: someValue)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MyOtherView, context: Context) {
        print(myValue)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: MyView
        
        init(_ parent: MyView) {
            print("init() called")
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
}
```

When the value myValue changes in my ContentView I need to reinitialize MyView, but the init()-method is only called once, when first running the app. It never gets called when I change the binding variable myValue. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You would have to recreate the whole thing, you can try using “id()” on MyView but recreating a view is usually a poor design choice, you should update your UI instead

Comment: I'm trying to reorganizing my code, but I'm stuck at some stuff needed to be initialized before the view is created. I may have to rethink my whole project to get around it.

Comment: I agree with @loremipsum. What is the purpose to reinitialize the `Coordinator`? The life cycle of the view follows the parent view. Usually you just `update` the view. `updateUIView` is called when `myValue` changes.